# d3-bar-chart-and-line-chart доработать чтобы было как на картинке

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

```js
var dataArray = [
                 ['category A',5,200], 
     ['category B',10,100],
     ['Some text ...long C',19,30],
     ['D',4,50],
                 ['category Q',5,20],
     ['category R',10,10], 
     ['Some text ...long S',19,350],
     ['T',40,500]                                                   
                ];

plot_bar_line_graph(dataArray, "#bar_line_chart", 600, 300, 'yLabel', 'yLabel2');


// A function to plot D3 line chart - Pass in the data array and the html objectId
// where the chart needs to be.
// Also pass the width, height for the plot
function plot_bar_line_graph (dataArray, htmlObjectId, width, height, yLabel, yLabel2) {

    // set margins for a nice looking bar chart
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Determine max data to set the axis limits
    var maxData = Math.max.apply(Math,dataArray.map(function(d){return d[1];}));
    var minData = Math.min.apply(Math,dataArray.map(function(d){return d[1];}));
    var maxData2 = Math.max.apply(Math,dataArray.map(function(d){return d[2];}));
    var minData2 = Math.min.apply(Math,dataArray.map(function(d){return d[2];}));
    

    // Define linear scale for y-axis
    // Note that the height range is reversed. 
    var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .range([height, margin.top])
                            // change 0 to minData is required
                            .domain([0,maxData])
                            ;
    
    // height scale for bar graphs on right
    var heightScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .range([height, margin.top])
                            .domain([0,maxData2])
                            ;

    // define scale for categorical x-axis
    // NOTE: The range is from margin.left and not 0.
    var widthScale = d3.scaleBand()
                        .range([margin.left, width])
                        .padding(0.4)
                        .domain(dataArray.map(function(d) { return d[0]; }))
                        ;

    // define x,y-axes scale and align them bottom and left
    var yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(heightScale)
                .tickSize(3)
                ;

    var yaxis2 = d3.axisRight()
                .scale(heightScale2)
                .tickSize(3)
                ;


    var xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(widthScale)
                .tickSize(0)
                ;

    // Define the canvas which will hold the chart
    var canvas = d3.select(htmlObjectId)
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    ;

     // Define the line and bind it to the data
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {return widthScale(d[0]) + widthScale.bandwidth()/2; })
        .y(function(d) {return heightScale(d[1]); })
        .curve(d3.curveLinear)
        ;

    // add bars to the canvas                
    var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(dataArray)
                    .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("class", "bar")
                        .attr("y", function(d) {return heightScale2(d[2]);})
                        .attr("x", function(d) {return widthScale(d[0]);})
                        .attr("height", function(d) {return height - heightScale2(d[2]);})
                        .attr("width", widthScale.bandwidth())
                        .attr("fill", "DodgerBlue")
                        .style("opacity", 0.7)
                        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                            d3.select(this).attr("fill","orangered");
                                div.transition()
                                    .duration(200)
                                    .style("opacity", 0.9);
                                div.html("скорость " + d[1] + ",<br/> интенсивность " + d[2])
                                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

                        })
                        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                            d3.select(this).attr("fill","DodgerBlue");
                                div.transition()  
                                    .duration(200)  
                                    .style("opacity", 1);                            
                        })                        
                        .on("click", function(d) {
                            console.log(d);
                        })
                        ;        

    // Draw line connecting the data points
    // Do not fill!
    canvas.append("path")
        .data([dataArray])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "Green")
  .style("opacity", 0.6)
        //.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("d", line)
        ;

  

    // Define the div for the tooltip
    // The styling and locations need css definitions.
    var div = d3.select(htmlObjectId)
                .append("div") 
                .attr("class", "tooltip")    
                .style("opacity", 0);


     // Add dots for data points. 
     // Also includes tooltip
    canvas.selectAll("dot")
        .data(dataArray)
        .enter()
     .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return widthScale(d[0]) + widthScale.bandwidth()/2; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return heightScale(d[1]); })
        .attr("fill", "Green")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9);
            div.html("скорость " + d[1] + ",<br/> интенсивность " + d[2])
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {  
            div.transition()  
                .duration(200)  
                .style("opacity", 0); 
        })
        ;



//оси координат
    // Add x-axis to the bar chart canvas низ
    canvas.append("g")
                .call(xaxis)
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .attr("class", "axis x")  
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-4")
                .attr("dy", "4")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-75)" )
                ;


    // add y-axis to the bar chart canvas лево
    canvas.append("g")
                .call(yaxis)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left +", 0)")
                .attr("class", "axis y")  
            .append("text")
                //.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("dy", "1.2em")
                .attr("dx", "-5em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(yLabel)
                .attr("fill", "Green");
                ;

    // add y-axis2 to the bar chart canvas право
    canvas.append("g")
                .call(yaxis2)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width +", 0)")
                .attr("class", "axis y2")  
            .append("text")
               // .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("dy", "-0.2em")
                .attr("dx", "-5em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(yLabel2)
                .attr("fill", "DodgerBlue");
                ;
                                
}
```

```css
div.tooltip { 
        position: absolute;   
        text-align: center;   
        width: 120px;     
        height: 30px;     
        padding: 2px;    
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        color: white;  
        background:black; 
        border: 0px;  
        border-radius: 8px;   
        pointer-events: none;   
    }
 body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>D3 Bar chart</title>

    

   </head>
   <body>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        
        <div id="bar_line_chart"></div>

        <script src="bar_line_chart.js"> </script>


   </body>
</html>
```

---

не сталкивался ранее с d3 .проблема с отрисовкой зеленой линии (которая полупрозрачна) и с перекрестьем (которое красного цвета)
недавно на этом форуме,прилагаемый код работает но не корректно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

помогите разобраться и подогнать к исходному условию ( которое на картинке) код

```js
var JSONdata={
 "measurementPoints": [
  
    {
      "speedValue": 84.684,
   "Value": 54,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:05:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 86.099,
   "Value": 35,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:10:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 86.572,
   "Value": 12,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:15:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 86.871,
   "Value": 22,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:20:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 86.961,
   "Value": 41,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:25:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 87.429,
   "Value": 15,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:30:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 87.03,
   "Value": 10,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:35:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 87.46,
   "Value": 55,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:40:00"
    },
    {
      "speedValue": 86.763,
   "Value": 10,
      "measurementDateTime": "2016-06-09T17:45:00"
    }
  ],
  "sensorId": 145
};



 // This is the format our dates are in, e.g 23/05/2014
 var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');

 var dates = [],
     dateStrings = [],
     temps = [];
  temps2 = [];
 var frequencyData=[];

 JSONdata.measurementPoints.forEach(function(d) {

  // Keep array of original date strings
  dateStrings.push(d.measurementDateTime);

  // Convert date string into JS date, add it to dates array
  dates.push(timeFormat.parse(d.measurementDateTime));

  // Add high temperature to temps array
  temps.push(+d.speedValue);
  // Add high temperature to temps array
  temps2.push(+d.Value);
 });
  //set up chart base details
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 80, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 250, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;
  //div container for the chart
 var container = d3.select('#temp-chart');
  //creating svg element
 var svg = container.append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

  //add graphichal object for later usage
 var defs = svg.append('defs');

 // clipping area for drawing
 defs.append('clipPath') 
  .attr('id', 'plot-area-clip-path')
  .append('rect')
   .attr({
    x: margin.left,
    y: margin.top,
    width: width - margin.right - margin.left,
    height: height - margin.top - margin.bottom
   });

 // Invisible background rect to capture all zoom events
 var backRect = svg.append('rect')
  .style('stroke', 'none')
  .style('fill', '#FFF')
  .style('fill-opacity', 0)
  .attr({
   x: margin.left,
   y: margin.top,
   width: width - margin.right - margin.left,
   height: height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   'pointer-events': 'all'
  });

 var axes = svg.append('g')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'none')
  .style('font-size', '10px');

 var chart = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'plot-area')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'none')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#plot-area-clip-path)');

 // x scale
 var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .domain(d3.extent(dates));

 // Calculate the range of the temperature data
 var yExtent = d3.extent(temps);
 var yExtent2 = d3.extent(temps2);
 var yRange = yExtent[1] - yExtent[0];

 // Adjust the lower and upper bounds to force the data
 // to fit into the y limits nicely
 yExtent[0] = yExtent[0] - yRange * 0.1;
 yExtent[1] = yExtent[1] + yRange * 0.1;

 yExtent2[0] = yExtent2[0] - yRange * 0.1;
 yExtent2[1] = yExtent2[1] + yRange * 0.1;
 // the y scale
 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
  .domain(yExtent);
 // the y scale                       2    
 var yScale2 = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
  .domain(yExtent2); 
 // x axis
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient('bottom')
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .innerTickSize(0)
  .scale(xScale);

 // y axis вертикали 1
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient('left')
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .innerTickSize(- (width - margin.left - margin.right))  // trick for creating quick gridlines
  .scale(yScale);
    // y axis вертикали 2                    2
 var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient('right')
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .innerTickSize(0)
  .scale(yScale2);

 // Add the x axis to the chart
 var xAxisEl = axes.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + (height - margin.bottom) + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

 // Add the y axis to the chart
 var yAxisEl = axes.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + 0 + ')')
  .call(yAxis);

 // Add the y axis to the chart
 var yAxisEl2 = axes.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis right')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width - margin.right) + ',' + 0 + ')')
  .call(yAxis2);

 // Format y-axis gridlines
 yAxisEl.selectAll('line')
  .style('stroke', '#BBB')
  .style('stroke-width', '1px')
  .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges');

// Format y-axis gridlines                     2
 yAxisEl2.selectAll('line')
  .style('stroke', '#BBB')
  .style('stroke-width', '1px')
  .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges');  
  
 // Start data as a flat line at the average
 var avgTempY = yScale(d3.mean(temps));
 // Start data as a flat line at the average                                       2
 var avgTempY = yScale(d3.mean(temps2));


 
 // Path generator function for our data
 var pathGenerator = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(dates[i]); })
  .y(function(d, i) { return yScale(temps[i]); });
 // Path generator function for our data                                          2
 var pathGenerator2 = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(dates[i]); })
  .y(function(d, i) { return yScale2(temps2[i]); });
  
 // Series container element
 var series = chart.append('g');
 
 // Add the temperature series path to the chart                                    2
 var path2 = series.append('path')
  .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'green')
  .style('stroke-width', '5px')
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('d', pathGenerator2(dates)); 
 // Add the temperature series path to the chart
 var path = series.append('path')
  .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('stroke-width', '1px')
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr('d', pathGenerator(dates));



  
  
  
 // Add zooming and panning functionality, only along the x axis
 var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 12])
  .x(xScale)
  .on('zoom', function zoomHandler() {
      //debugger;
   axes.select('.x-axis')
    .call(xAxis);
   series.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate[0] + ',0) scale(' + d3.event.scale + ',1)');

  });


 // The backRect captures zoom/pan events
 backRect.call(zoom);


 // Function for resetting any scaling and translation applied
 // during zooming and panning. Returns chart to original state.
 function resetZoom() {

  zoom.scale(1);
  zoom.translate([0, 0]);
  
  // Set x scale domain to the full data range
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(dates));

  // Update the x axis elements to match
  axes.select('.x-axis')
   .transition()
   .call(xAxis);

  // Remove any transformations applied to series elements
  series.transition()
   .attr('transform', "translate(0,0) scale(1,1)");
    
    path.attr('d', pathGenerator(dates));
    path2.attr('d', pathGenerator2(dates)); //                                          2
 
    xAxis.scale(xScale);
    xAxisEl.call(xAxis);

 };

// Call resetZoom function when the button is clicked
d3.select("#reset-zoom").on("click", resetZoom);
// Call scaleMonth function when the button is clicked
//d3.select("#monthButton").on("click", scaleMonth);
 // Call scaleMonth function when the button is clicked
//d3.select("#dayButton").on("click", scaleDay);
 // Call scaleMonth function when the button is clicked
//d3.select("#hourButton").on("click", scaleHour);
//d3.select("#okButton").on("click", scaleFrequency);
 // Active point element
 var activePoint = svg.append('circle')
  .attr({
   cx: 0,
   cy: 0,
   r: 5,
   'pointer-events': 'none'
  })
  .style({
   stroke: 'none',
   fill: 'red',
   'fill-opacity': 0
  });


 // Set container to have relative positioning. This allows us to easily
 // position the tooltip element with absolute positioning.
 container.style('position', 'relative');

 // Create the tooltip element. Hidden initially.
 var tt = container.append('div')
  .style({padding: '5px',
   border: '1px solid #AAA',
   color: 'black',
   position: 'absolute',
   visibility: 'hidden',
   'background-color': '#F5F5F5'
  });
//debugger;


 // Function for hiding the tooltip
 function hideTooltip() {
  tt.style('visibility', 'hidden');
  activePoint.style('fill-opacity', 0);

 }


 // Function for showing the tooltip
 function showTooltip() {
  tt.style('visibility', 'visible');
  activePoint.style('fill-opacity', 1);

 }


 // Tooltip content formatting function
 function tooltipFormatter(date, temp,temp2) {

  var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%d %b %Y %X');
  return dateFormat(date) + '<br><b><strong>скорость :' + temp.toFixed(1) + '<br><b><strong>интенсивность :' + temp2.toFixed(1);

 }



 backRect.on('mousemove', function() {
  // Coords of mousemove event relative to the container div
  var coords = d3.mouse(container.node());

  // Value on the x scale corresponding to this location
  var xVal = xScale.invert(coords[0]);
  var d = new Date(xVal.getTime());
    d.setSeconds(0);
    if(frequencyData.length!==0)
    d.setMinutes(0);
  // Format the date object as a date string matching our original data
  var date = timeFormat(d);
   // debugger;
  // Find the index of this date in the array of original date strings
  var i = dateStrings.indexOf(date);

  // Does this date exist in the original data?
  var dateExists = i > -1;

  // If not, hide the tooltip and return from this function
  if (!dateExists) {
   hideTooltip();
   return;
  }

  // If we are here, the date was found in the original data.
  // Proceed with displaying tooltip for of the i-th data point.

  // Get the i-th date value and temperature value.
  var _date = dates[i],
      _temp = temps[i];
   _temp2 = temps2[i];
  // Update the position of the activePoint element
  activePoint.attr({
   cx: xScale(_date),
   cy: yScale(_temp)
  });

  // Update tooltip content
  tt.html(tooltipFormatter(_date, _temp,_temp2));

  // Get dimensions of tooltip element
  var dim = tt.node().getBoundingClientRect();

  // Update the position of the tooltip. By default, above and to the right
  // of the mouse cursor.
  var tt_top = coords[1] - dim.height - 10,
      tt_left = coords[0] + 10;

  // If right edge of tooltip goes beyond chart container, force it to move
  // to the left of the mouse cursor.
  if (tt_left + dim.width > width)
   tt_left = coords[0] - dim.width - 10;

  tt.style({
   top: tt_top + 'px',
   left: tt_left + 'px'
  });
  
  // Show tooltip if it is not already visible
  if (tt.style('visibility') != 'visible')
   showTooltip();

 });


 // Add mouseout event handler
 backRect.on('mouseout', hideTooltip);
```

```css
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #FFF;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  clip-path: url(#plot-area-clip-path);
  stroke: red;

}
.line:nth-of-type(2) {
  stroke: blue;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>18102017</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="reset-zoom">Reset zoom</button>






<div id="temp-chart"></div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что именно вас не устраивает в текущей реализации и с чем возникли проблемы?

Comment: Андрей, если невозможно востановить старый логин, задайте новый вопрос с содержимым текущего. Редактировать свой собственный вопрос под именем другого пользователя не имеет смысла.

Comment: Напишу сотруднику, ваши учетки объединят в одну.

Comment: зачем что-то объединять? мне нужна помощь в коде ,как реализовать его?

Comment: что , никого нет чтоб разобраться?)

Answer (score 1):

Для отрисовки заполненной линии используйте area() вместо line(). Я не очень понял что за красные линии, используйте svg элемент `line` для их отрисовки. Кроме того, для того, чтоб показывать корректно tooltip, вам нужно будет определять положение курсора и определять какой прямоугольник под ним и его подсвечивать. Это нужно из-за того, что area chart перекрывает собой bar chart.

```js
var dataArray = [
  ['category A', 5, 200],
  ['category B', 10, 100],
  ['Some text ...long C', 19, 30],
  ['D', 4, 50],
  ['category Q', 5, 20],
  ['category R', 10, 10],
  ['Some text ...long S', 19, 350],
  ['T', 40, 500]
];

plot_bar_line_graph(dataArray, "#bar_line_chart", 600, 300, 'yLabel', 'yLabel2');


// A function to plot D3 line chart - Pass in the data array and the html objectId
// where the chart needs to be.
// Also pass the width, height for the plot
function plot_bar_line_graph(dataArray, htmlObjectId, width, height, yLabel, yLabel2) {

  // set margins for a nice looking bar chart
  var margin = {
      top: 30,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Determine max data to set the axis limits
  var maxData = Math.max.apply(Math, dataArray.map(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  }));
  var minData = Math.min.apply(Math, dataArray.map(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  }));
  var maxData2 = Math.max.apply(Math, dataArray.map(function(d) {
    return d[2];
  }));
  var minData2 = Math.min.apply(Math, dataArray.map(function(d) {
    return d[2];
  }));


  // Define linear scale for y-axis
  // Note that the height range is reversed. 
  var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, margin.top])
    // change 0 to minData is required
    .domain([0, maxData]);

  // height scale for bar graphs on right
  var heightScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, margin.top])
    .domain([0, maxData2]);

  // define scale for categorical x-axis
  // NOTE: The range is from margin.left and not 0.
  var widthScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([margin.left, width])
    .padding(0.4)
    .domain(dataArray.map(function(d) {
      return d[0];
    }));

  // define x,y-axes scale and align them bottom and left
  var yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(heightScale)
    .tickSize(10);

  var yaxis2 = d3.axisRight()
    .scale(heightScale2)
    .tickSize(10);


  var xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(widthScale)
    .tickSize(10);

  // Define the canvas which will hold the chart
  var canvas = d3.select(htmlObjectId)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  // Define the line and bind it to the data
  var line = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return widthScale(d[0]) + widthScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    })
    .y1(function(d) {
      return heightScale(d[1]);
    })
    .curve(d3.curveLinear);

  // add bars to the canvas                
  var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return heightScale2(d[2]);
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return widthScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - heightScale2(d[2]);
    })
    .attr("width", widthScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("fill", "DodgerBlue")
    .style("opacity", 0.7)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr("fill", "orangered");
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0.9);
      div.html("скорость " + d[1] + ",<br/> интенсивность " + d[2])
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr("fill", "DodgerBlue");
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      console.log(d);
    });

  line.y0(height);

  // Draw line connecting the data points
  // Do not fill!
  canvas.append("path")
    .data([dataArray])
    .attr("fill", "#1F521F")
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0.6)
    .attr("stroke", "#00FF00")
    //.style("opacity", 0.6)
    //.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    //.attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("d", line);



  // Define the div for the tooltip
  // The styling and locations need css definitions.
  var div = d3.select(htmlObjectId)
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);


  // Add dots for data points. 
  // Also includes tooltip
  canvas.selectAll("dot")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return widthScale(d[0]) + widthScale.bandwidth() / 2;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return heightScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr('stroke', '#00FF00')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html("скорость " + d[1] + ",<br/> интенсивность " + d[2])
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });



  //оси координат
  // Add x-axis to the bar chart canvas низ
  canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xaxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-14")
    .attr("dy", "-6")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-75)");


  // add y-axis to the bar chart canvas лево
  canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", 0)")
    .attr("class", "axis y")
    .call(yaxis)
    .append("text")
    //.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", "1.2em")
    .attr("dx", "-5em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(yLabel)
    .attr("fill", "Green");;

  // add y-axis2 to the bar chart canvas право
  canvas.append("g")
    .call(yaxis2)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .attr("class", "axis y2")
    .append("text")
    // .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", "-0.2em")
    .attr("dx", "-5em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(yLabel2)
    .attr("fill", "DodgerBlue");;

}
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
}

.axis text {
  fill: white;
}

.axis line {
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D3 Bar chart</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bar_line_chart"></div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спасиб , хоть чтот ) да , доработать бы . а то по сравнению с amcharts тут 100 строк чтоб  добавить всего лишь одну доработку. а перекрестье чтот на подобие https://codepen.io/Yurchenko/pen/dGQZay?limit=all&page=3&q=d3js , https://codepen.io/djantelmen/pen/wayOBa?limit=all&page=3&q=D3+line+ . но у меня возникла сложность их совместить(

Comment: @andrej94 Второй пример хороший. Простой и показательный. Попробуйте его смотреть. В нём создаётся прямоугольник на всю ширину графика и по этому прямоугольнику определяется ближайшая точка.